# Unable to build ios app in xamarin visual studio

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, compiler-errors, xamarin.ios

i am using visual studio 2017 and imac computer with OSX EI captain.and successfully connected mac to pc installed all requires things. but i am now getting following error, while building app, 
and i am unable to upgrade xcode to 8 on mac it keeps loading.[error while compiling the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7NId.png)

Comment: Xamarin requires XCode 9 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was unable to update xcode from app store, solved it using following steps,
1) goto app store download ios sierra.
2) update your mac.
3) then from app store you will get the update automatically.
hope it will help someone in futur.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, Xamarin need XCode 8 as the minimum version. If you can't upgrade your XCode from the App Store try to download it [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), select the version that you want and just wait to finish, I had the same issue some time ago and after doing this everything started to work.

Comment: thanks for responding, but i was unable to upgrade ios from app store. solved it by using ios sierra